# Relation between dense subsets in the product map and dense subsets in each component

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $\Omega$ bea Polish space and $X_1,\dots,X_n:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ be Borel measurable maps. Consider now the map $X:\Omega\rightarrow(\mathbb R^d)^n$ defined by $X(\omega)=(X_1(\omega),\dots,X_n(\omega)).$

For $i=1,\dots,n$ there exists a sequence $(\omega_{ik})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\overline{Im(X_i)}=\overline{(X_i(\omega_{ik}))_{k\in\mathbb N}},$ where $Im(X_i)$ is the image of $X_i.$ Do we have that $$\overline{Im(X)}=\overline{(X(\omega_{ik}))_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\},k\in\mathbb N}}?$$

Similarly, there exists a sequence $(\omega_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\Omega$ such that $\overline{Im(X)}=\overline{(X(\omega_k))_{k\in\mathbb N}}.$ Do we have that $$\overline{Im(X_i)}=\overline{(X_i(\omega_k))_{k\in\mathbb N}}$$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is not true:

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2$, $d=1$, $X_1(x,y)=x$ and $X_2(x,y)=y$. Then $X(x,y)=(x,y)$. Let $(q_n)$ be an enumeration of the rationals. Consider $\omega_{1k}=(q_n,0)$ and $\omega_{2k}=(0,q_n)$ then $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(X_i)}=\overline{(X_i(\omega_{ik}))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}}$, but $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(X)}\neq\overline{(X(\omega_{ik}))_{i\in\left\{1,2\right\},k\in\mathbb{N}}}$.

The second statement is true: Just use continuity of the projection $p_i:(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in(\mathbb{R}^d)^n\mapsto x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$.